Buttons and text not displayed in Fragments
I am testing bottom navigation for an Android app. In the fragment, the views—the buttons and Text views requires a larger height to display the text correctly; using wrap_content or a smaller height does not work. Can somebody help me?
Image showing the design and simulation 
activity_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

fragment.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BlankFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="184dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="87dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="78dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="246dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editTextText2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="83dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="238dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="71dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="129dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="47dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editTextText"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="133dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="Name" />

</RelativeLayout>

MainActivity.java
package lk.uu.testbottomnav2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.renderscript.ScriptGroup;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;  //****custom code ****
    InFragment inFragment = new InFragment();  //****custom code ****
    EditFragment editFragment = new EditFragment();  //****custom code ****


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation); //****custom code ****

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,inFragment).commit(); //****custom code ****
        bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

                int itemId = item.getItemId();
                if (itemId == R.id.input) {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, inFragment).commit();
                } else if (itemId == R.id.edit) {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, editFragment).commit();
                }



                return false;
            }
        }


        );
    }
}

